# How to collect all results from $.get inside a loop before further js execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a js for loop and inside the loop it goes out to get values from a php script.

how can i collect all values before the script executes further?

what i have now:

```
for(var i=0; i<TabelArray.length; i++) {
  $.get({
        url: drawURL + '/tabelPrice&name=' + name + '&width='+ width + '&height=' + height,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log("succes");
        console.log(data);
    }, 
    error: function() {
       callback(false);
    }
    });
}
console.log("after loop");
```

prints out:
"after loop"
"value 1"
"value 2"

where as i would suspect/ need:
"value 1"
"value 2"
"after loop"

Comment: you are looking for `async: false,` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). note - *Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.*

Comment: That Ajax is asynchronous. Your console log will executed with no regards to when are what the call returns.

Comment: Not `async: false`, either use promises or a pub/sub pattern.

Comment: with async: false i get  deprecation warnings.

Comment: [*As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until all calls have returned, using callbacks:

```
var results = [];

var after_loop = function () {
  console.log("after loop");
  // do whatever you want with results
};

var process_data_ok = function (data) {
  console.log(data);

  results.push(data);
  if ( results.length == TabelArray.length ) {
    after_loop();
  }
};

var process_data_fail = function () {
  console.log(false);

  results.push(false);
  if ( results.length == TabelArray.length ) {
    after_loop();
  }
};

for(var i=0; i<TabelArray.length; i++) {
  $.get({
    url: drawURL + '/tabelPrice&name=' + name + '&width='+ width + '&height=' + height,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: process_data_ok, 
    error: process_data_fail
  });
}
```

Comment: Or `Promise.all()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all